# Add a block on the top of the page content in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, magento2.2

I'm running Magento 2.0.1. I want to show a block in the checkout page. So, I created a module to override the checkout page. I have added the block code in the `checkout_index_index.xml` file, but the block shows at the bottom of the page.

I want to render the block on the top of the page without using Knockout.js.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- block code -->
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ClassName" name="content.options" after="-" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>

<!-- Checkout page components -->
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        ...
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`before="checkout.root"`** to show your content at the top of checkout page

Your final `checkout_index_index.xml` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ClassName" name="content.options" template="Vendor_Module::myfile.phtml" before="checkout.root" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for.